# Request for Sierra screenshot of 2 folders

Tags: macos

Can anyone running the released version of Sierra post screenshots of the folders:
Library>Fonts and System>Library>Fonts?

Got something I want to check about deprecated system fonts, but I don't have a noncritical machine I really want to install Sierra to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is from macOS Sierra 10.12, downloaded yesterday from the App Store.

```
$ ls -l /Library/Fonts
total 265360
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    124996 Jul 30 16:48 Al Nile.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     76572 Jul 30 16:48 Al Tarikh.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    178720 Jul 30 16:48 AlBayan.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2410616 Aug  6 22:48 AmericanTypewriter.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    109700 Aug  6 22:48 Andale Mono.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    335572 Aug  6 22:48 Apple Chancery.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  15292988 Nov 13  2014 AppleGothic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  18757920 Apr 21  2015 AppleMyungjo.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    122556 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Black.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    558672 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    750984 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    553284 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    183932 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Narrow Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    184420 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Narrow Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    184944 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Narrow Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    179492 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Narrow.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     49296 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Rounded Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  23278008 Aug  6 22:48 Arial Unicode.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    773236 Aug  6 22:48 Arial.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2310148 Aug  6 22:48 Athelas.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    304592 Jul 30 16:48 Ayuthaya.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    106220 Jul 30 16:48 Baghdad.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    429068 Jul 30 16:48 Bangla MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    365072 Jul 30 16:48 Bangla Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1330920 Aug  6 22:48 Baskerville.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     78976 Jul 30 16:48 Beirut.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    213512 Aug  6 22:48 BigCaslon.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    230216 Aug  6 22:48 Bodoni 72 OS.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     79956 Aug  6 22:48 Bodoni 72 Smallcaps Book.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    416692 Aug  6 22:48 Bodoni 72.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     72492 Aug  6 22:48 Bodoni Ornaments.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    592324 Aug  6 22:48 Bradley Hand Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    222640 Aug  6 22:48 Brush Script.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    166072 Aug  6 22:48 Chalkboard.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    519772 Aug  6 22:48 ChalkboardSE.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    483652 Aug  6 22:48 Chalkduster.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2097188 Aug  6 22:48 Charter.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1224236 Aug  6 22:48 Cochin.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    120120 Aug  6 22:48 Comic Sans MS Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    135484 Aug  6 22:48 Comic Sans MS.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1257000 Aug  6 22:48 Copperplate.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     71784 Jul 30 16:48 Corsiva.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    506640 Aug  6 22:48 Courier New Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    691796 Aug  6 22:48 Courier New Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    589900 Aug  6 22:48 Courier New Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    684624 Aug  6 22:48 Courier New.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    147024 Aug  6 22:48 DIN Alternate Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     82260 Aug  6 22:48 DIN Condensed Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1973380 Jul 30 16:48 Damascus.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     94640 Jul 30 16:48 DecoTypeNaskh.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    414396 Jul 30 16:48 Devanagari Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    406212 Jul 30 16:48 DevanagariMT.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    712936 Aug  6 22:48 Didot.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     90540 Jul 30 16:48 Diwan Kufi.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1318280 Jul 30 16:48 Diwan Thuluth.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    550984 Jul 30 16:48 EuphemiaCAS.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     88452 Jul 30 16:48 Farah.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    279940 Jul 30 16:48 Farisi.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    502120 Aug  6 22:48 Futura.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    385768 Aug  6 22:48 Georgia Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    363800 Aug  6 22:48 Georgia Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    400624 Aug  6 22:48 Georgia Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    379588 Aug  6 22:48 Georgia.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1220852 Aug  6 22:48 GillSans.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    222388 Jul 30 16:48 Gujarati Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    381112 Jul 30 16:48 GujaratiMT.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     87460 Jul 30 16:48 Gurmukhi MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     80636 Jul 30 16:48 Gurmukhi Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     63936 Jul 30 16:48 Gurmukhi.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    107692 Aug  6 22:48 Herculanum.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     41544 Aug  6 22:48 Hoefler Text Ornaments.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1632416 Aug  6 22:48 Hoefler Text.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    826144 Jul 30 16:48 ITFDevanagari.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    138488 Aug  6 22:48 Impact.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    260064 Jul 30 16:48 InaiMathi.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3356712 Aug  6 22:48 Iowan Old Style.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1175268 Jul 30 16:48 Kailasa.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    511428 Jul 30 16:48 Kannada MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    465676 Jul 30 16:48 Kannada Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    389880 Jul 30 16:48 Kefa.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    436596 Jul 30 16:48 Khmer MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    155560 Jul 30 16:48 Khmer Sangam MN.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    677004 Jul 30 16:48 Kokonor.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    186800 Jul 30 16:48 Krungthep.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     85588 Jul 30 16:48 KufiStandardGK.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     85352 Jul 30 16:48 Lao MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     38824 Jul 30 16:48 Lao Sangam MN.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    553520 Aug  6 22:48 Luminari.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    174380 Jul 30 16:48 Malayalam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    159240 Jul 30 16:48 Malayalam Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    915352 Aug  6 22:48 Marion.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    652248 Aug  6 22:48 Microsoft Sans Serif.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    658260 Jul 30 16:48 Mishafi Gold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1425292 Jul 30 16:48 Mishafi.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    169024 Jul 30 16:48 Mshtakan.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    197916 Jul 30 16:48 Muna.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    225784 Jul 30 16:48 Myanmar MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    162772 Jul 30 16:48 Myanmar Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7108788 Jul 31 23:18 NISC18030.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     59452 Jul 30 16:48 Nadeem.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    148656 Jul 30 16:48 NewPeninimMT.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    251312 Jul 30 16:48 Oriya MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    215452 Jul 30 16:48 Oriya Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    309348 Aug  6 22:48 PTMono.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2767520 Jul 30 16:48 PTSans.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1151720 Aug  6 22:48 PTSerif.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    700100 Aug  6 22:48 PTSerifCaption.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1104648 Aug  6 22:48 Papyrus.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    223020 Aug  6 22:48 Phosphate.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     72052 Jul 30 16:48 PlantagenetCherokee.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     63248 Jul 30 16:48 Raanana.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    369156 May 11  2012 STIXGeneral.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    186612 May 11  2012 STIXGeneralBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    143764 May 11  2012 STIXGeneralBolIta.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    141844 May 11  2012 STIXGeneralItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16992 May 11  2012 STIXIntDBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     17500 May 11  2012 STIXIntDReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16608 May 11  2012 STIXIntSmBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     17416 May 11  2012 STIXIntSmReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16576 May 11  2012 STIXIntUpBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16932 May 11  2012 STIXIntUpDBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16964 May 11  2012 STIXIntUpDReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16856 May 11  2012 STIXIntUpReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16916 May 11  2012 STIXIntUpSmBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     17184 May 11  2012 STIXIntUpSmReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     54556 May 11  2012 STIXNonUni.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     25508 May 11  2012 STIXNonUniBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     41188 May 11  2012 STIXNonUniBolIta.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     46268 May 11  2012 STIXNonUniIta.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     13464 May 11  2012 STIXSizFiveSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12628 May 11  2012 STIXSizFourSymBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15656 May 11  2012 STIXSizFourSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12924 May 11  2012 STIXSizOneSymBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     19004 May 11  2012 STIXSizOneSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12636 May 11  2012 STIXSizThreeSymBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15648 May 11  2012 STIXSizThreeSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12576 May 11  2012 STIXSizTwoSymBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15620 May 11  2012 STIXSizTwoSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     21776 May 11  2012 STIXVar.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     14808 May 11  2012 STIXVarBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     74936 Jul 30 16:48 Sana.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    414872 Jul 30 16:48 Sathu.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    101512 Aug  6 22:48 Savoye LET.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   4983524 Aug  6 22:48 Seravek.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    520156 Jul 30 16:48 Shree714.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    397316 Aug  6 22:48 SignPainter.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    288864 Jul 30 16:48 Silom.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    642736 Jul 30 16:48 Sinhala MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    328636 Jul 30 16:48 Sinhala Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    489424 Aug  6 22:48 Skia.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3587668 Aug  6 22:48 SnellRoundhand.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  66954320 Jul 31 23:18 Songti.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    626056 Jul 30 16:48 SukhumvitSet.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2681496 Aug  6 22:48 SuperClarendon.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    626928 Aug  6 22:48 Tahoma Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    681120 Aug  6 22:48 Tahoma.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    190204 Jul 30 16:48 Tamil MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    148524 Jul 30 16:48 Tamil Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    807688 Jul 30 16:48 Telugu MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    606924 Jul 30 16:48 Telugu Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    620008 Aug  6 22:48 Times New Roman Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    842168 Aug  6 22:48 Times New Roman Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    660268 Aug  6 22:48 Times New Roman Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    834452 Aug  6 22:48 Times New Roman.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1160004 Aug  6 22:48 Trattatello.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    137008 Aug  6 22:48 Trebuchet MS Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    129360 Aug  6 22:48 Trebuchet MS Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    144820 Aug  6 22:48 Trebuchet MS Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    138848 Aug  6 22:48 Trebuchet MS.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    173132 Aug  6 22:48 Verdana Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    153260 Aug  6 22:48 Verdana Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    174612 Aug  6 22:48 Verdana Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    186188 Aug  6 22:48 Verdana.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    368184 Jul 30 16:48 Waseem.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    124308 Aug  6 22:48 Webdings.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     68768 Aug  6 22:48 Wingdings 2.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     38308 Aug  6 22:48 Wingdings 3.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     86384 Aug  6 22:48 Wingdings.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    406468 Aug  6 22:48 Zapfino.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  11409608 Oct  9  2015 ヒラギノ丸ゴ ProN W4.ttc
$ 

$ ls -l /System/Library/Fonts
total 785616
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    263912 Aug  6 22:48 Apple Braille Outline 6 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    280980 Aug  6 22:48 Apple Braille Outline 8 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    183080 Aug  6 22:48 Apple Braille Pinpoint 6 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    189668 Aug  6 22:48 Apple Braille Pinpoint 8 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    135960 Aug  6 22:48 Apple Braille.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  90421904 Aug  6 22:48 Apple Color Emoji.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    973516 Aug  6 22:48 Apple Symbols.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  28386056 Aug 11  2015 AppleSDGothicNeo.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  18487164 Nov  7  2014 AquaKana.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    192088 Jul 30 16:48 ArialHB.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3325568 Aug  6 22:48 Avenir Next Condensed.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   5045468 Aug  6 22:48 Avenir Next.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1593228 Aug  6 22:48 Avenir.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1646421 Aug  6 22:48 Courier.dfont
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1023944 Aug  6 22:48 GeezaPro.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    750818 Aug  6 22:48 Geneva.dfont
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    181804 Aug  6 22:48 HelveLTMM
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2563430 Aug  6 22:48 Helvetica.dfont
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   6739979 Aug  6 22:48 HelveticaNeue.dfont
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   5377548 Aug  6 22:48 HelveticaNeueDeskInterface.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  13187340 Jul 31 23:18 Hiragino Sans GB W3.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  13249216 Jul 31 23:18 Hiragino Sans GB W6.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     55840 Aug  6 22:48 Keyboard.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    907504 Jul 30 16:48 Kohinoor.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    635128 Jul 30 16:48 KohinoorBangla.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    343244 Jul 30 16:48 KohinoorTelugu.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      3044 Aug  6 22:48 LastResort.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3181856 Aug  6 22:48 LucidaGrande.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    621152 Aug  6 22:48 MarkerFelt.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2134884 Aug  6 22:48 Menlo.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    563895 Aug  6 22:48 Monaco.dfont
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    551924 Aug  6 22:48 Noteworthy.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    253740 Aug  6 22:48 Optima.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1770652 Aug  6 22:48 Palatino.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  80376964 Jul 31 23:18 PingFang.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    288120 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Black.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    312640 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    313248 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    310664 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    313620 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    306876 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    313492 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Semibold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    309476 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Thin.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    309320 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactDisplay-Ultralight.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    178988 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Black.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    193664 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    193508 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    191380 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    193788 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    187600 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    193812 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Semibold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    193080 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Thin.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    192088 Jul  6 15:19 SFCompactRounded-Ultralight.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    306152 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    167884 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-BoldItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    303736 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    167004 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-HeavyItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    299932 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    169716 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-LightItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    307168 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    168604 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-MediumItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    301796 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    167984 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-RegularItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    307160 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-Semibold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    168200 Jul 31 13:08 SFCompactText-SemiboldItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1271388 Jul 31 13:08 SFNSDisplay.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    145624 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Black.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    157096 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    156080 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    157376 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    155440 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    150940 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    156284 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Semibold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    155928 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Thin.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    154988 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSDisplayCondensed-Ultralight.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1761608 Jul 31 13:08 SFNSText.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    169580 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSTextCondensed-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    168520 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSTextCondensed-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    168364 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSTextCondensed-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    167356 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSTextCondensed-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    163036 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSTextCondensed-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    168296 Jul 13 16:26 SFNSTextCondensed-Semibold.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    879792 Jul 31 13:08 SFNSTextItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  55997812 Jul 31 23:18 STHeiti Light.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  55966692 Jul 31 23:18 STHeiti Medium.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    109612 Aug  6 22:48 Symbol.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2411184 Jul 30 16:48 Thonburi.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1599593 Aug  6 22:48 Times.dfont
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    208494 Aug  6 22:48 TimesLTMM
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    154132 Aug  6 22:48 ZapfDingbats.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  11867472 Oct  9  2015 ヒラギノ明朝 ProN W3.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  11975732 Oct  9  2015 ヒラギノ明朝 ProN W6.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3567792 Jul 14  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W0.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7286744 Jul 14  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W1.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7270552 Jul 14  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W2.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7891480 Sep 18  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W3.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7259328 Jul 14  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W4.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7260984 Jul 14  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W5.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7998200 Sep 18  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W6.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3607768 Jul 14  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W7.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   4096288 Oct  9  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W8.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3464676 Jul 14  2015 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W9.ttc
$
```