# Request for list of fonts folder contents on Monterey

Tags: font, monterey

I was wondering if anyone could run a list of fonts on Monterey, similar to [my question 5 years ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253883/request-for-sierra-screenshot-of-2-folders). Curious about changes to system fonts but don't want to install Monterey just yet. Command below:

```
ls -l /Library/Fonts
ls -l /System/Library/Fonts
```

Comment: You might wanna take a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded **macOS Monterey** 12.0.1 from the **App Store** and on a pristine clean install, no previous **OS** installed, here are the complete contents of `/Library/Fonts/` and `/System/Library/Fonts/` which includes `/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental`.

Note the *date* discrepancies between `May  4`, `Feb 18` and other *dates* in the other answer compared to just `Oct 17` in a clean install done with **macOS Monterey** 12.0.1 from the **App Store**.

Also note that in the other answer it shows the following *directories* in `/System/Library/Fonts/` and they do not exist in a clean install of **macOS Monterey** with what I just downloaded from the **App Store**:

```
drwxr-xr-x   80 root  wheel      2560 Feb 18  2021 Latin Modern/
drwxrwxr-x  161 root  wheel      5152 Feb 18  2021 Microsoft/
drwxr-xr-x   41 root  wheel      1312 Feb 18  2021 TeX Gyre/
```

### Base install of Fonts in **macOS Monterey** 12.0.1:

```
% ls -lR {/System,}/Library/Fonts
/Library/Fonts:
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  52 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Unicode.ttf -> /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Arial Unicode.ttf

/System/Library/Fonts:
total 964120
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     266008 Oct 17 23:30 Apple Braille Outline 6 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     283076 Oct 17 23:30 Apple Braille Outline 8 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     185180 Oct 17 23:30 Apple Braille Pinpoint 6 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     191768 Oct 17 23:30 Apple Braille Pinpoint 8 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     138012 Oct 17 23:30 Apple Braille.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  216899436 Oct 17 23:30 Apple Color Emoji.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     897936 Oct 17 23:30 Apple Symbols.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   28429272 Oct 17 23:30 AppleSDGothicNeo.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   18494124 Oct 17 23:30 AquaKana.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     459376 Oct 17 23:30 ArialHB.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3284564 Oct 17 23:30 Avenir Next Condensed.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    4988788 Oct 17 23:30 Avenir Next.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1639536 Oct 17 23:30 Avenir.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1148048 Oct 17 23:30 Courier.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1018224 Oct 17 23:30 GeezaPro.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     736708 Oct 17 23:30 Geneva.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     181804 Oct 17 23:30 HelveLTMM
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    2369376 Oct 17 23:30 Helvetica.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    4472088 Oct 17 23:30 HelveticaNeue.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   25879292 Oct 17 23:30 Hiragino Sans GB.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel      58088 Oct 17 23:30 Keyboard.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1041880 Oct 17 23:30 Kohinoor.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     696040 Oct 17 23:30 KohinoorBangla.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     538284 Oct 17 23:30 KohinoorGujarati.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     672280 Oct 17 23:30 KohinoorTelugu.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel       2468 Oct 17 23:30 LastResort.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3200332 Oct 17 23:30 LucidaGrande.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     627492 Oct 17 23:30 MarkerFelt.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    2155812 Oct 17 23:30 Menlo.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     534204 Oct 17 23:30 Monaco.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1394452 Oct 17 23:30 MuktaMahee.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     495468 Oct 17 23:30 NewYork.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     522980 Oct 17 23:30 NewYorkItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     561924 Oct 17 23:30 Noteworthy.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     921108 Oct 17 23:30 NotoNastaliq.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     171832 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansArmenian.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1047492 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansKannada.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1727576 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMyanmar.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     318396 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOriya.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1150952 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSerifMyanmar.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     263984 Oct 17 23:30 Optima.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1786600 Oct 17 23:30 Palatino.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   77143236 Oct 17 23:30 PingFang.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     699200 Oct 17 23:30 SFArabic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1704228 Oct 17 23:30 SFCompact.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     952388 Oct 17 23:30 SFCompactItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     937084 Oct 17 23:30 SFCompactRounded.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    8167388 Oct 17 23:30 SFNS.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1000016 Oct 17 23:30 SFNSItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     218648 Oct 17 23:30 SFNSMono.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     199236 Oct 17 23:30 SFNSMonoItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1649536 Oct 17 23:30 SFNSRounded.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   55783456 Oct 17 23:30 STHeiti Light.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   55754164 Oct 17 23:30 STHeiti Medium.ttc
drwxr-xr-x  285 root  wheel       9120 Oct 17 23:30 Supplemental
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel      80016 Oct 17 23:30 Symbol.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    2421960 Oct 17 23:30 Thonburi.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     918880 Oct 17 23:30 Times.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     208494 Oct 17 23:30 TimesLTMM
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     156088 Oct 17 23:30 ZapfDingbats.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   19409608 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ明朝 ProN.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    9718696 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ丸ゴ ProN W4.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3571264 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W0.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7266168 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W1.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7249436 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W2.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7876852 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W3.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7238080 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W4.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7238572 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W5.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7978872 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W6.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3607376 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W7.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3755372 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W8.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3469048 Oct 17 23:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W9.ttc

/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental:
total 262032
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    109124 Oct 17 23:30 Academy Engraved LET Fonts.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    131264 Oct 17 23:30 Al Nile.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     79748 Oct 17 23:30 Al Tarikh.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    188132 Oct 17 23:30 AlBayan.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2440184 Oct 17 23:30 AmericanTypewriter.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    109700 Oct 17 23:30 Andale Mono.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    336452 Oct 17 23:30 Apple Chancery.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  15255648 Oct 17 23:30 AppleGothic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  18760352 Oct 17 23:30 AppleMyungjo.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    122556 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Black.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    558672 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    750984 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    553284 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    183932 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Narrow Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    184420 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Narrow Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    184944 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Narrow Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    179492 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Narrow.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     49296 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Rounded Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  23278008 Oct 17 23:30 Arial Unicode.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    773236 Oct 17 23:30 Arial.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2325812 Oct 17 23:30 Athelas.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    307268 Oct 17 23:30 Ayuthaya.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    109492 Oct 17 23:30 Baghdad.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    316524 Oct 17 23:30 Bangla MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    439724 Oct 17 23:30 Bangla Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1371312 Oct 17 23:30 Baskerville.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     81672 Oct 17 23:30 Beirut.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    223272 Oct 17 23:30 BigCaslon.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    238724 Oct 17 23:30 Bodoni 72 OS.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     82788 Oct 17 23:30 Bodoni 72 Smallcaps Book.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    427652 Oct 17 23:30 Bodoni 72.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     73972 Oct 17 23:30 Bodoni Ornaments.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    596216 Oct 17 23:30 Bradley Hand Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    222640 Oct 17 23:30 Brush Script.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    176872 Oct 17 23:30 Chalkboard.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    536756 Oct 17 23:30 ChalkboardSE.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    486860 Oct 17 23:30 Chalkduster.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2118332 Oct 17 23:30 Charter.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1240320 Oct 17 23:30 Cochin.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    120120 Oct 17 23:30 Comic Sans MS Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    135484 Oct 17 23:30 Comic Sans MS.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1266824 Oct 17 23:30 Copperplate.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     76120 Oct 17 23:30 Corsiva.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    506640 Oct 17 23:30 Courier New Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    691796 Oct 17 23:30 Courier New Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    589900 Oct 17 23:30 Courier New Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    684624 Oct 17 23:30 Courier New.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    151528 Oct 17 23:30 DIN Alternate Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    211644 Oct 17 23:30 DIN Condensed Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3027948 Oct 17 23:30 Damascus.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     97544 Oct 17 23:30 DecoTypeNaskh.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1027920 Oct 17 23:30 Devanagari Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    409696 Oct 17 23:30 DevanagariMT.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    722884 Oct 17 23:30 Didot.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     93724 Oct 17 23:30 Diwan Kufi.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1319880 Oct 17 23:30 Diwan Thuluth.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    543868 Oct 17 23:30 EuphemiaCAS.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     91112 Oct 17 23:30 Farah.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    281512 Oct 17 23:30 Farisi.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    488604 Oct 17 23:30 Futura.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    430932 Oct 17 23:30 Galvji.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    385768 Oct 17 23:30 Georgia Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    363800 Oct 17 23:30 Georgia Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    400624 Oct 17 23:30 Georgia Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    379588 Oct 17 23:30 Georgia.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1253700 Oct 17 23:30 GillSans.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    545740 Oct 17 23:30 Gujarati Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    384332 Oct 17 23:30 GujaratiMT.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    229944 Oct 17 23:30 Gurmukhi MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    143344 Oct 17 23:30 Gurmukhi Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     65540 Oct 17 23:30 Gurmukhi.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    111124 Oct 17 23:30 Herculanum.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     43380 Oct 17 23:30 Hoefler Text Ornaments.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1645672 Oct 17 23:30 Hoefler Text.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    817376 Oct 17 23:30 ITFDevanagari.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    138488 Oct 17 23:30 Impact.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    457432 Oct 17 23:30 InaiMathi-MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3419188 Oct 17 23:30 Iowan Old Style.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1178132 Oct 17 23:30 Kailasa.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    342980 Oct 17 23:30 Kannada MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    296796 Oct 17 23:30 Kannada Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    361144 Oct 17 23:30 Kefa.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    495056 Oct 17 23:30 Khmer MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    188048 Oct 17 23:30 Khmer Sangam MN.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    676076 Oct 17 23:30 Kokonor.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    190152 Oct 17 23:30 Krungthep.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     57728 Oct 17 23:30 KufiStandardGK.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     96348 Oct 17 23:30 Lao MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     58092 Oct 17 23:30 Lao Sangam MN.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    557856 Oct 17 23:30 Luminari.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    175056 Oct 17 23:30 Malayalam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    185216 Oct 17 23:30 Malayalam Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    927292 Oct 17 23:30 Marion.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    652248 Oct 17 23:30 Microsoft Sans Serif.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    649384 Oct 17 23:30 Mishafi Gold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1426864 Oct 17 23:30 Mishafi.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    176224 Oct 17 23:30 Mshtakan.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    207352 Oct 17 23:30 Muna.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    242060 Oct 17 23:30 Myanmar MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    193720 Oct 17 23:30 Myanmar Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7110652 Oct 17 23:30 NISC18030.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     62716 Oct 17 23:30 Nadeem.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    157392 Oct 17 23:30 NewPeninimMT.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     61236 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansAdlam-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12888 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansAvestan-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    148664 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansBamum-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      7740 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansBassaVah-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15148 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansBatak-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    220044 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansBhaiksuki-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     39428 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansBrahmi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      7236 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansBuginese-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      5612 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansBuhid-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6688 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansCarian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     26828 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansCaucasianAlbanian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     41592 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansChakma-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     30208 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansCham-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     28084 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansCoptic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    820316 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansCuneiform-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      8332 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansCypriot-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     18724 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansDuployan-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    585444 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansEgyptianHieroglyphs-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     11172 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansElbasan-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     23264 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansGlagolitic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6152 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansGothic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     32372 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansGunjalaGondi-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     19400 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansHanifiRohingya-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      7896 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansHanunoo-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      5020 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansHatran-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6500 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansImperialAramaic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6032 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansInscriptionalPahlavi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      7792 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansInscriptionalParthian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     86944 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansJavanese-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     62716 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansKaithi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      9464 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansKayahLi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     25388 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansKharoshthi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     42632 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansKhojki-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     19032 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansKhudawadi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     24500 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansLepcha-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12912 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansLimbu-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     58140 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansLinearA-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     64828 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansLinearB-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6516 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansLisu-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      4556 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansLycian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      4592 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansLydian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     14144 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMahajani-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     18908 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMandaic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     31448 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansManichaean-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    125956 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMarchen-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     23052 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMasaramGondi-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16044 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMeeteiMayek-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     35360 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMendeKikakui-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     33644 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMeroitic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     36236 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMiao-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     42688 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansModi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    135484 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMongolian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6904 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMro-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      9856 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansMultani-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     23236 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansNKo-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      8400 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansNabataean-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     17000 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansNewTaiLue-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    149024 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansNewa-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      8860 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOlChiki-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     54020 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOldHungarian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      7524 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOldItalic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      7284 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOldNorthArabian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      9984 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOldPermic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     13180 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOldPersian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      5232 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOldSouthArabian-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      8372 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOldTurkic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12512 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOsage-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      8604 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansOsmanya-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     18272 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansPahawhHmong-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15684 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansPalmyrene-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      9816 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansPauCinHau-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     34176 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansPhagsPa-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6252 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansPhoenician-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     21676 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansPsalterPahlavi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      7620 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansRejang-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     11164 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansSamaritan-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     19792 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansSaurashtra-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     44108 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansSharada-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    142328 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansSiddham-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      8108 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansSoraSompeng-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     11512 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansSundanese-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16576 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansSylotiNagri-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    179132 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansSyriac-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6656 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansTagalog-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      6648 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansTagbanwa-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12072 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansTaiLe-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     51040 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansTaiTham-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     18220 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansTaiViet-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16652 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansTakri-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     18792 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansThaana-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15356 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansTifinagh-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     69944 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansTirhuta-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      7656 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansUgaritic-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     57764 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansVai-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     17992 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansWancho-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     25304 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansWarangCiti-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    134064 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSansYi-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     19512 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSerifAhom-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     51264 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSerifBalinese-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      8664 Oct 17 23:30 NotoSerifYezidi-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    214204 Oct 17 23:30 Oriya MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    180460 Oct 17 23:30 Oriya Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    315876 Oct 17 23:30 PTMono.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2794628 Oct 17 23:30 PTSans.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1164836 Oct 17 23:30 PTSerif.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    706700 Oct 17 23:30 PTSerifCaption.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1110432 Oct 17 23:30 Papyrus.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    213112 Oct 17 23:30 PartyLET-plain.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    230964 Oct 17 23:30 Phosphate.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     75012 Oct 17 23:30 PlantagenetCherokee.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     43728 Oct 17 23:30 Raanana.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    487456 Oct 17 23:30 Rockwell.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    369156 Oct 17 23:30 STIXGeneral.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    186612 Oct 17 23:30 STIXGeneralBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    143764 Oct 17 23:30 STIXGeneralBolIta.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    141844 Oct 17 23:30 STIXGeneralItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16992 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntDBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     17500 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntDReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16608 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntSmBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     17416 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntSmReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16576 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntUpBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16932 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntUpDBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16964 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntUpDReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16856 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntUpReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     16916 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntUpSmBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     17184 Oct 17 23:30 STIXIntUpSmReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     54556 Oct 17 23:30 STIXNonUni.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     25508 Oct 17 23:30 STIXNonUniBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     41188 Oct 17 23:30 STIXNonUniBolIta.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     46268 Oct 17 23:30 STIXNonUniIta.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     13464 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizFiveSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12628 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizFourSymBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15656 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizFourSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12924 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizOneSymBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     19004 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizOneSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12636 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizThreeSymBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15648 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizThreeSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     12576 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizTwoSymBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     15620 Oct 17 23:30 STIXSizTwoSymReg.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     21776 Oct 17 23:30 STIXVar.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     14808 Oct 17 23:30 STIXVarBol.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     77604 Oct 17 23:30 Sana.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    417676 Oct 17 23:30 Sathu.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    109256 Oct 17 23:30 Savoye LET.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   6253688 Oct 17 23:30 Seravek.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    531372 Oct 17 23:30 Shree714.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    400316 Oct 17 23:30 SignPainter.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    291508 Oct 17 23:30 Silom.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    780240 Oct 17 23:30 Sinhala MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    757768 Oct 17 23:30 Sinhala Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    489984 Oct 17 23:30 Skia.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3588844 Oct 17 23:30 SnellRoundhand.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  66933080 Oct 17 23:30 Songti.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    356420 Oct 17 23:30 SukhumvitSet.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2712224 Oct 17 23:30 SuperClarendon.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    626928 Oct 17 23:30 Tahoma Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    681120 Oct 17 23:30 Tahoma.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    188700 Oct 17 23:30 Tamil MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    313276 Oct 17 23:30 Tamil Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    333016 Oct 17 23:30 Telugu MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    305548 Oct 17 23:30 Telugu Sangam MN.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    620008 Oct 17 23:30 Times New Roman Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    842168 Oct 17 23:30 Times New Roman Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    660268 Oct 17 23:30 Times New Roman Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    834452 Oct 17 23:30 Times New Roman.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    932128 Oct 17 23:30 Trattatello.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    137008 Oct 17 23:30 Trebuchet MS Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    129360 Oct 17 23:30 Trebuchet MS Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    144820 Oct 17 23:30 Trebuchet MS Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    138848 Oct 17 23:30 Trebuchet MS.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    173132 Oct 17 23:30 Verdana Bold Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    153260 Oct 17 23:30 Verdana Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    174612 Oct 17 23:30 Verdana Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    186188 Oct 17 23:30 Verdana.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    370732 Oct 17 23:30 Waseem.ttc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    124308 Oct 17 23:30 Webdings.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     68768 Oct 17 23:30 Wingdings 2.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     38308 Oct 17 23:30 Wingdings 3.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     86384 Oct 17 23:30 Wingdings.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    403264 Oct 17 23:30 Zapfino.ttf
%
```

Comment: Thanks!  Normally Apple does publish and official note with a list of fonts provided with every MacOS version, but it's not yet out for Monterey.  Big Sur s at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211240

Comment: Inevitable question: How do we delete them?! One of the first things I do with a new system is nuke the fonts down to the minimum so I can run a clean system, but with this new file system, I'm at a loss for how to customise my OS. Yes, I know how to turn them off in FontBook, but I want them gone-gone. 600 MB of useless crap (with a few system critical ones, I know).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls -l {/System,}/Library/Fonts
/Library/Fonts:
total 441744
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    143932 May  4  2012 ACaslonPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    169784 May  4  2012 ACaslonPro-BoldItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    168372 May  4  2012 ACaslonPro-Italic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    168852 May  4  2012 ACaslonPro-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    172256 May  4  2012 ACaslonPro-Semibold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    171092 May  4  2012 ACaslonPro-SemiboldItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     74952 May  4  2012 AGaramondPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     76452 May  4  2012 AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     91916 May  4  2012 AGaramondPro-Italic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    127592 May  4  2012 AGaramondPro-Regular.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Academy Engraved LET Fonts
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    360784 May  4  2012 AdobeArabic-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    358032 May  4  2012 AdobeArabic-BoldItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    369512 May  4  2012 AdobeArabic-Italic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    376016 May  4  2012 AdobeArabic-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5497908 May  4  2012 AdobeFanHeitiStd-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  14526060 May  4  2012 AdobeFangsongStd-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   2832152 May  4  2012 AdobeGothicStd-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     81204 May  4  2012 AdobeHebrew-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     85252 May  4  2012 AdobeHebrew-BoldItalic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     85608 May  4  2012 AdobeHebrew-Italic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     82080 May  4  2012 AdobeHebrew-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  12265424 May  4  2012 AdobeHeitiStd-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  16948908 May  4  2012 AdobeKaitiStd-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  10171656 May  4  2012 AdobeMingStd-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4059096 May  4  2012 AdobeMyungjoStd-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  15586660 May  4  2012 AdobeSongStd-Light.otf
-rw-rw-r--    1 root  wheel     57456 Jan 25  2007 AppleCasual.dfont
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        52 Oct 18 05:30 Arial Unicode.ttf@ -> /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Arial Unicode.ttf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Bank Gothic
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     36452 May  4  2012 BirchStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Blackmoor LET Fonts
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     44468 May  4  2012 BlackoakStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Jun 15  2006 BlairMdITC TT-Medium
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Bodoni Ornaments ITC TT
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Bodoni SvtyTwo ITC TT
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Bodoni SvtyTwo OS ITC TT
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Bodoni SvtyTwo SC ITC TT
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Apr 26  2007 Bordeaux Roman Bold LET Fonts
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Bradley Hand ITC TT-Bold
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     35456 May  4  2012 BrushScriptStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--    1 root  wheel     75698 Mar  7  2007 Capitals.dfont
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    132408 May  4  2012 ChaparralPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    133864 May  4  2012 ChaparralPro-BoldIt.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    133256 May  4  2012 ChaparralPro-Italic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    132236 May  4  2012 ChaparralPro-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     36888 May  4  2012 CharlemagneStd-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     36536 May  4  2012 CooperBlackStd-Italic.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     34960 May  4  2012 CooperBlackStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Jun 15  2006 Cracked
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     47760 May  4  2012 GiddyupStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Jun 15  2006 Handwriting - Dakota
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     31040 May  4  2012 HoboStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Jazz LET Fonts
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5645912 May  4  2012 KozGoPr6N-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5050524 May  4  2012 KozGoPr6N-ExtraLight.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5806292 May  4  2012 KozGoPr6N-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5431800 May  4  2012 KozGoPr6N-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5499164 May  4  2012 KozGoPr6N-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5439252 May  4  2012 KozGoPr6N-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   3586872 May  4  2012 KozGoPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   3252652 May  4  2012 KozGoPro-ExtraLight.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   3670080 May  4  2012 KozGoPro-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   3456772 May  4  2012 KozGoPro-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   3496008 May  4  2012 KozGoPro-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   3460376 May  4  2012 KozGoPro-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8218100 May  4  2012 KozMinPr6N-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8155128 May  4  2012 KozMinPr6N-ExtraLight.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8436112 May  4  2012 KozMinPr6N-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8133548 May  4  2012 KozMinPr6N-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8161600 May  4  2012 KozMinPr6N-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8134748 May  4  2012 KozMinPr6N-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4383792 May  4  2012 KozMinPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   3825720 May  4  2012 KozMinPro-ExtraLight.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4268536 May  4  2012 KozMinPro-Heavy.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4233784 May  4  2012 KozMinPro-Light.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4313040 May  4  2012 KozMinPro-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4247988 May  4  2012 KozMinPro-Regular.otf
drwxr-xr-x   80 root  wheel      2560 Feb 18  2021 Latin Modern/
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     33244 May  4  2012 LetterGothicStd-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     34852 May  4  2012 LetterGothicStd-BoldSlanted.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     34972 May  4  2012 LetterGothicStd-Slanted.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     33444 May  4  2012 LetterGothicStd.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     79396 May  4  2012 LithosPro-Black.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     78428 May  4  2012 LithosPro-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     50920 May  4  2012 MesquiteStd.otf
drwxrwxr-x  161 root  wheel      5152 Feb 18  2021 Microsoft/
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    230912 May  4  2012 MinionPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    232680 May  4  2012 MinionPro-BoldCn.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    275572 May  4  2012 MinionPro-BoldCnIt.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    276632 May  4  2012 MinionPro-BoldIt.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    276140 May  4  2012 MinionPro-It.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    233088 May  4  2012 MinionPro-Medium.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    275004 May  4  2012 MinionPro-MediumIt.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    231312 May  4  2012 MinionPro-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    234260 May  4  2012 MinionPro-Semibold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    277068 May  4  2012 MinionPro-SemiboldIt.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Mona Lisa Solid ITC TT
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     95684 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     94628 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-BoldCond.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    100312 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-BoldCondIt.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    100252 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-BoldIt.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     91964 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-Cond.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     97888 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-CondIt.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     98064 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-It.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     94360 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     95616 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-Semibold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    100184 May  4  2012 MyriadPro-SemiboldIt.otf
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     89620 Mar 19  2011 MyriadWebPro-Bold.ttf*
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     82720 Mar 19  2011 MyriadWebPro-Condensed.ttf*
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     87304 Mar 19  2011 MyriadWebPro-CondensedIt.ttf*
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     83600 Mar 19  2011 MyriadWebPro-Italic.ttf*
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     83568 Mar 19  2011 MyriadWebPro.ttf*
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     57060 Mar 19  2011 NuevaStd-Bold.otf*
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     55592 May  4  2012 NuevaStd-BoldCond.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     55492 May  4  2012 NuevaStd-BoldCondItalic.otf
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     57212 Mar 19  2011 NuevaStd-BoldItalic.otf*
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     56384 May  4  2012 NuevaStd-Cond.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     56196 May  4  2012 NuevaStd-CondItalic.otf
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     56888 Mar 19  2011 NuevaStd-Italic.otf*
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     56628 Mar 19  2011 NuevaStd-Regular.otf*
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     29124 May  4  2012 OCRAStd.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     35372 May  4  2012 OratorStd-Slanted.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     34024 May  4  2012 OratorStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Jun 15  2006 Palatino
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Party LET Fonts
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     36012 May  4  2012 PoplarStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Jun 15  2006 PortagoITC TT
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     35240 May  4  2012 PrestigeEliteStd-Bd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Princetown LET Fonts
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     68620 May  4  2012 RosewoodStd-Regular.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Santa Fe LET Fonts
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Savoye LET Fonts
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 SchoolHouse Cursive B.suit
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 SchoolHouse Printed A
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Snell Roundhand
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     29864 May  4  2012 StencilStd.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Stone Sans ITC TT
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Synchro LET Fonts
drwxr-xr-x   41 root  wheel      1312 Feb 18  2021 TeX Gyre/
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     98336 May  4  2012 TektonPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     97232 May  4  2012 TektonPro-BoldCond.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     99580 May  4  2012 TektonPro-BoldExt.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    111360 May  4  2012 TektonPro-BoldObl.otf
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel    110984 Mar 19  2011 TektonPro-Obl.otf*
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root  wheel     98612 Mar 19  2011 TektonPro-Regular.otf*
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     68676 May  4  2012 TrajanPro-Bold.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     68564 May  4  2012 TrajanPro-Regular.otf
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  wheel         0 Mar  7  2007 Type Embellishmnt One LET
-rw-r--r--    1 root  admin      4070 Feb 18  2021 encodings.dir
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    115899 Feb 18  2021 fonts.dir
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel      5438 Feb 18  2021 fonts.list
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    115899 Feb 18  2021 fonts.scale

/System/Library/Fonts:
total 964120
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     266008 Oct 18 05:30 Apple Braille Outline 6 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     283076 Oct 18 05:30 Apple Braille Outline 8 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     185180 Oct 18 05:30 Apple Braille Pinpoint 6 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     191768 Oct 18 05:30 Apple Braille Pinpoint 8 Dot.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     138012 Oct 18 05:30 Apple Braille.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  216899436 Oct 18 05:30 Apple Color Emoji.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     897936 Oct 18 05:30 Apple Symbols.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   28429272 Oct 18 05:30 AppleSDGothicNeo.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   18494124 Oct 18 05:30 AquaKana.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     459376 Oct 18 05:30 ArialHB.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3284564 Oct 18 05:30 Avenir Next Condensed.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    4988788 Oct 18 05:30 Avenir Next.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1639536 Oct 18 05:30 Avenir.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1148048 Oct 18 05:30 Courier.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1018224 Oct 18 05:30 GeezaPro.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     736708 Oct 18 05:30 Geneva.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     181804 Oct 18 05:30 HelveLTMM
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    2369376 Oct 18 05:30 Helvetica.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    4472088 Oct 18 05:30 HelveticaNeue.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   25879292 Oct 18 05:30 Hiragino Sans GB.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel      58088 Oct 18 05:30 Keyboard.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1041880 Oct 18 05:30 Kohinoor.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     696040 Oct 18 05:30 KohinoorBangla.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     538284 Oct 18 05:30 KohinoorGujarati.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     672280 Oct 18 05:30 KohinoorTelugu.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel       2468 Oct 18 05:30 LastResort.otf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3200332 Oct 18 05:30 LucidaGrande.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     627492 Oct 18 05:30 MarkerFelt.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    2155812 Oct 18 05:30 Menlo.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     534204 Oct 18 05:30 Monaco.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1394452 Oct 18 05:30 MuktaMahee.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     495468 Oct 18 05:30 NewYork.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     522980 Oct 18 05:30 NewYorkItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     561924 Oct 18 05:30 Noteworthy.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     921108 Oct 18 05:30 NotoNastaliq.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     171832 Oct 18 05:30 NotoSansArmenian.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1047492 Oct 18 05:30 NotoSansKannada.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1727576 Oct 18 05:30 NotoSansMyanmar.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     318396 Oct 18 05:30 NotoSansOriya.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1150952 Oct 18 05:30 NotoSerifMyanmar.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     263984 Oct 18 05:30 Optima.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1786600 Oct 18 05:30 Palatino.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   77143236 Oct 18 05:30 PingFang.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     699200 Oct 18 05:30 SFArabic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1704228 Oct 18 05:30 SFCompact.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     952388 Oct 18 05:30 SFCompactItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     937084 Oct 18 05:30 SFCompactRounded.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    8167388 Oct 18 05:30 SFNS.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1000016 Oct 18 05:30 SFNSItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     218648 Oct 18 05:30 SFNSMono.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     199236 Oct 18 05:30 SFNSMonoItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    1649536 Oct 18 05:30 SFNSRounded.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   55783456 Oct 18 05:30 STHeiti Light.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   55754164 Oct 18 05:30 STHeiti Medium.ttc
drwxr-xr-x  285 root  wheel       9120 Oct 18 05:30 Supplemental/
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel      80016 Oct 18 05:30 Symbol.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    2421960 Oct 18 05:30 Thonburi.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     918880 Oct 18 05:30 Times.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     208494 Oct 18 05:30 TimesLTMM
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     156088 Oct 18 05:30 ZapfDingbats.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   19409608 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ明朝 ProN.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    9718696 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ丸ゴ ProN W4.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3571264 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W0.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7266168 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W1.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7249436 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W2.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7876852 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W3.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7238080 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W4.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7238572 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W5.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    7978872 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W6.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3607376 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W7.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3755372 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W8.ttc
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    3469048 Oct 18 05:30 ヒラギノ角ゴシック W9.ttc
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Are the Adobe fonts (Caslon, Minion, Garamond, Myriad etc.) ones you installed yourself or are they from the system?

Comment: I think that a new install of MacOS will not have any fonts in Library/Fonts.  This will have only user installed fonts.